# Can we play a game online between iPhone & iPad using gamecenter?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

This might be a very simple question but after much searching on different forums and on google I couldn't find a suitable answer for it. So I finally decided to ask the question here.

I have developed a game recently for iPad with gamecenter support that allows the user to play the game in online mode i.e Multiplayer. Now my client wants me to make this game universal. So my question here is.

Does gamecenter allow to play a match between an iPhone and an iPad device or does it only allow to play on same type of devices i.e iPhone to iPhone and iPad to iPad. ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they use the same API, then I think iPhone and iPad should work.

Comment: @belgther can you please explain that what do you mean by same API ?

Comment: same API would be here same protocol, same SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tested my universal application on an iPhone and iPad and I was able to play the game using gamecenter on two different type of device i.e an iPhone and an iPad.